# JQuery Mobile - Put a data-icon in addition to the checkbox in an input checkbox

Tags: jquery-mobile

I would like to put a nice little `data-icon="star"` on some chekbox labels of a group of checkboxes. Is there a way to do so using jQuery `data-icon` or should I just do it directly in the CSS (in which case how do I get the same rendering as the one of `data-icon`?).

In a dream world, here is what would work:

```
<div data-role='fieldcontain' data-mini='true'>
<fieldset data-role='controlgroup'>
<input type='checkbox' name='cb1' id='cb1' />
<label for='cb1' data-icon='star'>special</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='cb2' id='cb2' />
<label for='cb2'>normal</label>
</fieldset></div>
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: well it's a start: http://jsfiddle.net/7qzhn/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use your own custom CSS or JS to do this, `data-icon` only works with `a` tags per the documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html

This is even more tricky because the icon's are entered as styled spans which is exactly how the jqm checkbox is rendered - they both use the `ui-icon` for some base styling and positioning.

If you tried to use a jquery function to append it after the jqm styling has worked its magic like so: http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/zt7cP/1/ - but again, the styling conflicts with the actual checkbox, but the functionality of the checkbox is still there.

Hope this gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you it is very clear. This is what I was afraid of but I will have to work around.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is only available in the latest jQuery mobile (1.4.5) but you can just add ui-icon via the "class" attribute.  So for this example it would look like this:

```
<div data-role='fieldcontain' data-mini='true'>
<fieldset data-role='controlgroup'>
<input type='checkbox' name='cb1' id='cb1' />
<label for='cb1' class='ui-icon-star'>special</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='cb2' id='cb2' />
<label for='cb2'>normal</label>
</fieldset></div>
```